# Setting the viewport size with Rselenium and PhantomJS

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm using RSelenium and PhantomJS to pull data from a site.

I'm trying to change the useragent and viewport size.  I've managed to adjust the useragent but I can't seem to adjust the viewport size.

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom()

eCap <- list(phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent 
             = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0",
             phantomjs.page.viewportsize = "width:1280, height:1024")

remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", extraCapabilities = eCap)

remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/")
remDr$findElement("id", "user-agent")$getElementText()[1]

remDr$close()
```

With the code below you can see the browser window is 400 x 300.

I've checked the PhantomJS docs and verified `phantomjs.page.viewportsize` is present.

Any ideas how I can adjust the viewportsize?

Comment: You can access the PhantomJS API using the phantomExecute method `remDr$phantomExecute("var page = this; page.viewportSize = {width: 1280,height: 1024};")`. This only works as far as I recall when you are driving PhantomJS directly as you are doing in this case.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - this is a useful trick to pass in JS although I think @Floo answer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
remDr$setWindowSize(1280L, 1024L)
```